# Using the REST-API with the getting started guide returns 500 error

Tags: loopbackjs, hyperledger-composer

Following the instructions at https://fabric-composer.github.io/start/getting-started-rest-api.html, testing the generated api with

```
curl -X GET --header "Accept: application/json" "http://0.0.0.0:3000/api/net.biz.digitalPropertyNetwork.LandTitle"
```

generates the following error

```
 {
  "error": {
    "statusCode": 500,
    "name": "Error",
    "message": "No registered namespace for type net_biz_digitalPropertyNetwork_LandTitle",
    "stack": "Error: No registered namespace for type net_biz_digitalPropertyNetwork_LandTitle\n    at ModelManager.getType (/Users/matt/Documents/workspaces/blockchain/src/github.com/fabric-composer/sample-applications/node_modules/composer-common/lib/modelmanager.js:265:23)\n    at ensureConnected.then (/Users/matt/Documents/workspaces/blockchain/src/github.com/fabric-composer/sample-applications/node_modules/composer-loopback-connector/lib/businessnetworkconnector.js:198:53)\n    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:129:7)"
  }
}
```

I see that the boot script swaps dots for underscores, is this needed somewhere else too, perhaps?

```
// this is required because LoopBack doesn't like dots in model schema names
    modelSchema.name = modelSchema.plural.replace(/\./g, '_');
```

For reference, here are the node dependencies of my loopback package

```
"dependencies": {
    "composer-loopback-connector": "^0.4.0",
    "compression": "^1.0.3",
    "cors": "^2.5.2",
    "helmet": "^1.3.0",
    "loopback": "^2.22.0",
    "loopback-boot": "^2.6.5",
    "loopback-component-explorer": "^2.4.0",
    "loopback-connector-composer": "^0.4.1",
    "loopback-datasource-juggler": "^2.39.0",
    "serve-favicon": "^2.0.1",
    "strong-error-handler": "^1.0.1"
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you're right about the boot script swapping the dots for underscores. This is due to loopback not accepting dots in model names so the boot script swaps them out and the connector takes account of that when it gets called by the loopback app.

This was a problem with the original connector which is in npm as `composer-connector-loopback`.  That version hasn't been removed yet but should be soon.

It has since been renamed to bring it in line with other loopback connectors and is also in npm as `loopback-connector-composer`.

I'll raise an issue to get the getting-started guide that you mentioned updated and if you can switch over to using the other connector then that should solve the problem. HTH.